# What is this key hole used for, it is located under my hand brake(See the attached picture)

Tags: ford, focus, design

I own a 2003 Ford Focus, made for EU and I wonder for what is this key hole designed for.[image]

Comment: Can you take a picture more in focus to show the symbols next to each key position

Comment: Car model and year?

Comment: @David - hthey said it's a 2003 Ford Focus...

Comment: @RoryAlsop Thanks. Sigh. Reading inaccurately strikes again.

Comment: lol - it happens. Especially on mobile, I find...

Comment: Does your ignition key operate it?

Answer (score 1):

Shift lock

My 02 Nissan had one. Someone rear ended me once, I couldn't get the car into gear from P. Turns out, the lock became engaged, needed to use my car key to unlock

Comment: The 99-900 (and maybe 9000) series Saab automobiles had the ignition switch and lock mounted down there; the key could only be removed if the gearbox had been shifted into reverse. There was no steering lock; the on-the-gearbox ignition switch arrangement met DOT requirements to disable the vehicle when the engine was off.